# SWT ToolBar : how to remove blue highlight on first ToolItem?

Tags: java, swt, toolbar

I created a ToolBar populated with ToolItems containing images and the first enabled image get a blue halo. 
How could I remove It?

Thanks

Comment: What operating system?  Is it the focus ring?

Comment: Yes, it's the focus ring (thanks I didn't know that name). How could I disable it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could either set the focus to a different control or try to create your ToolBar with the `SWT.NO_FOCUS` style.

Comment: SWT.NO_FOCUS is what I was looking for. Thanks